# Issues while converting an SVG file or PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format

I have a data [here](https://pastebin.com/kEBf2TUM). I plotted this data by `ListDensityPlot` and exported to SVG (or PDF) file for editing in Illustrator using the following code.

```
data = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjthO.png"],"Byte"]]]];
plot = ListDensityPlot[data];
Export["location",plot]
```

Here is a screenshot from Illustrator
[image]

Why all these labels became a raster file? How do I keep it as a vector? Am I doing something wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Nasser, I meant to say the same thing happens with both format

Comment: @Nasser, How do you deal with these situations?

Comment: This behavior most probably is OS-dependent. What is your OS?

Comment: Does this happen only with ticks? Does this happen for `ListPlot`? Does this happen for exporting text as PDF?

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part now.

Answer (score 1):

### Data & Plot

```
data = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/kEBf2TUM", "String"];

plot = ListDensityPlot[data];
```

### Export with and without Rasterization

```
Export["location1.PDF", plot, "AllowRasterization" -> False]
(* "location1.PDF" *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Export["location2.PDF", plot, "AllowRasterization" -> True]
(* "location2.PDF" *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Explanation

Result depends on the value of the `"AllowRasterization"` option, which by default us `Automatic`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Since we have suffered that third party sites(you know), I always avoid use those data in third party sites.So I have changed the original `data`..

Comment: @yode, no need in this case, pastebin has this post with expiration set to "Never".

Answer (score 0):

Ran your code in Mathematica 11.1.1 on Windows 10.  Exported a PDF as you showed.

Here is what I see in Adobe Acrobat PDF.

[image: Here is what I see in PDF file]

Here is what I see in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017.1.0 .

[image: Here is what I see in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017.1.0]

Do not see rasterizing problem.

Here is more zooming of lower right of plot.

[image]

Here I change the last frame tick label from 2.4 to 3.14 in Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

But I am not proficient with Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: I am currently using Mathematica 11.0, I will upgrade to 11.1.0 and check since 11.1.1 is not availble

Comment: It does not work in my case. Can you zoom the portion three times the size as of now  or Can you please check whether you can edit the label or not in Adobe illsustrator

Comment: I've zoomed the plot in Adobe Illustrator and put the zoomed image at the end of my original post.  I'm not very proficient with Illustrator.  When you ask whether I can edit "the label", do you mean, for example, can I change the "2.4" label to something else, such as "3.3", within Illustrator?

Comment: I believe I was able to change the last label from 2.4 to 3.14 within Adobe Ilustrator.  See repost of my original answer.  Does this help?

Comment: I got your point.Could you also tell me the size of the pdf file, please? . How long did it take to export?

Comment: It takes less than 2 seconds for the plot to Export to a PDF file on an older HP quad-core laptop.  The file size is reported as 8.96 MB (9,405,804 bytes).  Not as big as I expected.  As someone else has commented above, it may be that the result in Adobe Illustrator is operating system dependent.  I use Windows 10 here at home.